# React stop rerendering of parent component when slider is used

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**UPDATE based on Jayce444's comment**. I moved setting the timer outside of the component and this helped. Is a global variable the best idea tho?

```
let globalTimer = null;
const setSlidingTimer = (timer) => {
  globalTimer = timer;
};

const SearchJobs = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => console.log("<SearchJobs /> rendered"));

const [sliderValue, setSliderValue] = useState(20);

const sliderChangeHandler = (newValue) => {
    clearTimeout(globalTimer);
    const timer = setTimeout(setSliderValue, 300, newValue);
    setSlidingTimer(timer);
  };
```

**ORIGINAL POST:**

My React app suffers in performance from **too many rerenders** of a parent component because its children (mainly a slider) change the state too often when changing their value.

My idea (see sliderChangeHandler) was to wait sth like 300ms before updating the slider's value in the state to reduce the number of rerenders. Somehow this doesn't work yet. Is there anyone who could help me with especially the slider and apply a similar idea to the input box? Like **wait 300ms before updating the state. If the user types or slides again, reset the 300ms timer**.

Here is the parent code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import Col from "react-bootstrap/Col";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import InputGroup from "react-bootstrap/InputGroup";
import FormControl from "react-bootstrap/FormControl";

import Slider from "../UI/Slider/Slider";

const SearchJobs = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => console.log("<SearchJobs /> rendered"));

  const [sliderValue, setSliderValue] = useState(20);
  const [address, setAddress] = useState("");
  const [slidingTimeout, setSlidingTimeout] = useState("");

  const sliderChangeHandler = (event, newValue) => {
    clearTimeout(slidingTimeout);
    const timer = setTimeout(setSliderValue, 300, newValue);
    setSlidingTimeout(timer);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Col xs={12} md={7}>
        <InputGroup className="mb-3">
          <InputGroup.Prepend>
            <InputGroup.Text id="inputGroup-sizing-default">
              Adresse
            </InputGroup.Text>
          </InputGroup.Prepend>
          <FormControl
            aria-label="Address"
            aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default"
            placeholder="myAddress"
            value={address}
            onChange={(event) => setAddress(event.target.value)}
          />
        </InputGroup>
      </Col>
      <Col xs={12} md={5}>
        <Slider value={sliderValue} change={sliderChangeHandler} />
      </Col>
    </>
  );
};

export default SearchJobs;
```

And this is the slider component:

```
import React from "react";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Slider from "@material-ui/core/Slider";

const SliderComponent = (props) => {
  const marks = [
    {
      value: 0,
      label: "0 km",
    },

    {
      value: 50,
      label: "50 km",
    },
  ];

  function valuetext(value) {
    return `${value} km`;
  }

  return (
    <div className="ml-3 mr-3">
      <Typography id="discrete-slider-always" gutterBottom>
        Radius
      </Typography>
      <Slider
        defaultValue={20}
        value={props.sliderValue}
        onChange={(event, newValue) => props.change(event, newValue)}
        getAriaValueText={valuetext}
        aria-labelledby="discrete-slider-always"
        step={0.1}
        min={0}
        max={50}
        marks={marks}
        valueLabelDisplay="on"
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default SliderComponent;
```

Comment: The actual timer itself shouldn't be in state, you don't want changing it to cause a re-render. Make it a ref

Comment: @Jayce444 I am not familiar with Refs but used your approach (see updated post). Could you show an example of how to solve this with Refs?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generic debouncing function, for example:

```
const debounce = (inputFun, milliseconds) => {
  let timeout;

  return (...args) => {
    if(!timeout) {
      inputFun(...args);

      timeout = setTimeout(
        () => ( timeout = undefined ), 
        milliseconds
      );
    }
  };
};
```

Then u create a debounced `sliderChangeHandler` like this:

```
const sliderChangeHandler = debounce(event => {
    setSliderValue(event.target.value);
}, 300);
```

U might want to adjust the arguments of the `sliderChangeHandler` (don't know why u have `event` and `newValue`) to match your requirements.

Comment: I implemented your approach but it still re-renders for every slider movement. Does your debouncing function really clear the previously set timer if the func is triggered again? I need to clear previously set timers before setting a new one?

Comment: u can put a `console.log` below `inputFun(...args)` to check when it's being called, but yes it clears the timer.